# Symfony: internal forwarding vs render controller

Tags: symfony, php-7, symfony3.x

I have simple action in simple controller:

```
public function _targetAction(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $request = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();
    // ...
}
```

And two ways to call it. First:

```
// The same or other controller
public function topAction(Request $request)
{
    // forward to SimpleController:_target
    return $this->forward('AppBundle:Simple:_target');
}
```

Second from twig (subrequest):

```
// SimpleController
public function topAction(Request $request)
{
    // render
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Simple:top.html.twig');
}     

// top.html.twig
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Simple:_target')) }}
```

How can i idenitfy which way i get to the SimpleController::_targetAction in this method:

```
public function _targetAction(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    // what can i do here to uniquely identify current way
    // Note: $requestStack->getParentRequest() is not null in both cases
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Have you tried with `->isMasterRequest()` ?

Comment: @emix isMasterRequest i can only call on KernelEvent, not sure about it is a good idea try to get event in controller action.

Comment: This thing you are trying to do isn't a good idea at all. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @emix render controller - isn't good idea? Alternatives? I try to handle synchr. and ajax requests by one action (topAction), but if everything would be so simple, i would use isXmlHttpRequest()... Anyway, i've already found solution. But question stays opened.

Comment: You can use render controller third parameter, which is your `POST` keys/values `{{ render(controller(Controller:Action, { parameter: value }, { post_parameter: value })) }}`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you need to execute different code depending on the call type, you should considere create `separate routes` for each action.

In case you really want to use the same, my best shot is to add a parameter on the route to identify the request.

```
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/target/{from}", name="_target")
     */
    public function _targetAction($from)
    {
        if($from == 'view'){
            // execute code for view call
        } else {
            // execute code for controller call
        }
    }
```

And then, when you call it, pass a different parameter depending on caller type:

**TWIG**

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Simple:_target', { 'from': 'view' })) }}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
return $this->forward('_target', array('from' => 'controller'));
```

Comment: this is an obvious solution, its the first i thought about. But if only in targetAction?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better your question? only in targetAction?

Comment: I mean maybe it can be done inside Simple::_targetAction, using some "symptoms" of RequestStack, without passing extra parameters.

Comment: Maybe you can use `$currentRequest->headers->get('referer');` but in my opinion this contribute to complicate things.